# print somthing on the same line as subprocess output

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

I've come up with this code:

```
import os, subprocess, sys

location = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
file = os.path.basename(__file__)

#print location # + r'\' + file

user_in = raw_input(location + '>')
if user_in == 'cd ..':
    proc = subprocess.Popen('cd .. && cd', shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin= subprocess.PIPE)
    new_location = proc.stdout.read() + proc.stderr.read() + '>'
    #new_location = str(new_location) + '>'
    new_location = new_location.replace(r'\r','')
    new_location = new_location.replace(' ','')
    print new_location
    #new_user_in = raw_input(str(new_location) + '>')
    #subprocess.Popen('cd .. && ' + new_user_in, shell=True)
```

But when I run it and enter `cd ..` I get:

```
D:\Documents\Programmed\DesktopUnsorted
>
```

I dont want this because what I want it to do is:

```
D:\Documents\Programmed\DesktopUnsorted>
```

**EDIT**

I also already tried: `new_location = new_location.replace(r'\n','')`

But it doesnt change anything

Thanks,
Stefan

Comment: you need `new_location.replace(r'\n','')` too probably.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I already tried that. But thanks for taking the time to help. I edited my quistion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're overdoing your replacements by using `r` prefix. Python tries to replace literally `\n` and `r`, not the control chars. That works:

```
new_location = new_location.replace('\r','')
```

You'd be better off with `rstrip` anyway which removes all trailing space/newlines/carriage return chars:

```
new_location = proc.stdout.read().rstrip() + ">"
```

BTW your shell doesn't really work, since `cd` in subprocess doesn't change the directory for your current python process. You need `os.chdir` for that.

I'd improve it as is:

```
user_toks = user_in.split()
if len(user_toks)==2 and user_toks[0]=="cd":
   os.chdir(user_toks[1])
   # next command
   user_in = raw_input("{}> ".format(os.getcwd())
```

Comment: I know that it doesnt change the directory. That part is only for what the user sees, and its only part of the code im actualy making. But thanks for the awnser I totaly forgot I use r to take the backslashes litteraly otherwise my other codes wouldnt work